# Ruby block, procs and instance_eval

Tags: ruby, block, lambda, proc-object

I recently tried to do something akin to this:

```
a = "some string"
b = Proc.new{ upcase }
a.instance_eval b
```

Which gives the error:

> TypeError: can't convert Proc into String

but this works:

```
def b(&block)
  "some string".instance_eval &block
end

b{ upcase }
```

A further look with this method:

```
def b(&block)
  "some string".instance_eval block
end
```

Yields the same `Proc to String` error.

So...  my understanding of blocks is that they are just procs.  But there's obviously something special about having this `&` ampersand...

Can someone explain this to me?  Is it possible to convert a normal proc to be whatever it is that is special about this `&block` object?

#### edit

Just figured out my second question, prepend an `&` to the proc...  that was easy,  but WHAT is this really doing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All you have to do for your first example to work is this:

```
>> a.instance_eval &b #=> "SOME STRING"
```

The reason is that `instance_eval` needs either a string or a block and the ampersand provides the latter.

Comment: it's funny how i started to piece through this problem as i was writing this question and asking others... and in the end realized i just needed to know the difference between a proc and a block.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: dead link provided

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that `a.instance_eval b` is passing `b` as a regular argument to instance_eval, whereas `a.instance_eval &b` is passing it as a block.  Those are two different things.

Consider this method call:

```
obj.foo(bar) do |x| 
  stuff(x) 
end
```

That invokes the method `foo` with one regular argument (`bar`) and one block argument (`do |x| stuff(x) end`). In the method definition, they're distinguished by prefixing `&` to the block parameter:

```
def foo(arg, &block)
```

And if you wish to pass a variable expression instead of a literal block, that is likewise accomplished by prefixing *&* to the expression (which should yield a Proc).

If you pass an argument with no `&`, it goes in the *arg* slot instead of the *block* slot.  It doesn't matter that the argument happens to be an instance of Proc.  The syntax dictates how it is passed and treated by the method.

Comment: good concise answer, thanks!  (sorry i had already accepted @Michaels as he directed me to the diff between a block and Proc)

Answer (score 1):

It's because instance_eval accepts a string to eval or a block. `instance_eval(&block)` is passing your `block` as a block to instance_eval.

Comment: but what's the difference between a `block` and a `proc`?

Answer (score 1):

The crucial difference is that **a Proc instance is an object** whereas **a block is not an object**. The `&` is an operator that **interchanges a block and a Proc instance** mutually.

All arguments to a method must be an object. In addition to the arguments, a method can take a block. `instance_eval` is a method that takes either a String argument or a block. Passing a Proc object will satisfy neither case. If you attach `&` to a Proc object, that will be handeled as a block.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
a = "some string"
b = Proc.new{ upcase }
a.instance_eval &b
```

The `instance_eval` method can receive an block arguments.
`b` is a `Proc`.